# How to pause a Camel Quartz2 timer in a suspended route?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

The following unit test tries a quartz2 route that triggers each second:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CamelQuartzTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    static private String routeId = "test-route";

    @Test
    public void testSuspendRoute() throws Exception {
        // arrange
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");

        // act
        System.out.println("context.start()");
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(String.format("receivedCounter = %d", mock.getReceivedCounter()));

        System.out.println("context.startRoute()");
        context.startRoute(routeId);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(String.format("receivedCounter = %d", mock.getReceivedCounter()));

        System.out.println("context.suspendRoute()");
        context.suspendRoute(routeId);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(String.format("receivedCounter = %d", mock.getReceivedCounter()));

        System.out.println("context.resumeRoute()");
        context.resumeRoute(routeId);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(String.format("receivedCounter = %d", mock.getReceivedCounter()));

        System.out.println("context.stop()");
        context.stop();
        System.out.println(String.format("receivedCounter = %d", mock.getReceivedCounter()));

        // assert
        assertEquals(4, mock.getReceivedCounter());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("quartz2://testtimer?cron=0/1+*+*+?+*+*")
                .autoStartup(false)
                .routeId(routeId)
                .setBody()
                .simple("${header.triggerName}: ${header.fireTime}")
                .to("mock:result", "stream:out");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Result output:

```
context.start()
receivedCounter = 0
context.startRoute()
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:38 CEST 2014
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:39 CEST 2014
receivedCounter = 2
context.suspendRoute()
receivedCounter = 2
context.resumeRoute()
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:41 CEST 2014
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:41 CEST 2014
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:42 CEST 2014
testtimer: Tue Oct 21 10:06:43 CEST 2014
receivedCounter = 6
context.stop()
receivedCounter = 6
```

After resuming the route, the result shows 4 incoming triggers, while 2 were expected. Apparently, the quartz2 timer keeps firing while the route is suspended. How can I make quartz2 take a pause while the route is suspended?

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause: if a quartz job is suspended for a while, and resumed again, the default behavior of quartz is to catch up the triggers, aka "misfires", that were missed during the suspended period. I did not find a way the switch off this misfire behavior. However, decreasing the misfire threshold from 60 seconds to 500 ms helped in my case. This can be done by copying the default `quartz.properties` from `quartz-<version>.jar` to `org/quartz/quartz.properties` in the default classpath, and overrule the misfire threshold:

```
# Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance.
# This file overrules the default quartz.properties file in the
# quartz-<version>.jar  
#

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

# default threshold: 60 seconds
#org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
# overruled threshold: 500 ms, to prevent superfluous triggers after resuming
# a quartz job
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 500

org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```